# Web RTC connection is not established

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p

When I run this code connection is not established,

- in firefox console error "WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server and
  see about:webrtc for more details" shows up  and dataChannel.readyState is
  connecting
- in Chrome console error does not show up but again
  dataChannel.readyState is connecting

  ```
   var localconn, remoteconn, dataChannel, recievedDataChannel;
   connect();
   async function connect(){
       localconn = new RTCPeerConnection();
       remoteconn = new RTCPeerConnection();
       dataChannel = localconn.createDataChannel("dataChannel");

       dataChannel.onopen = e =>{
           console.log("data channel is open");
       }
       dataChannel.onmessage = e=>{
           console.log("new message: " +e.data);
       }

   remoteconn.ondatachannel = e =>{
       recievedDataChannel = e.channel;
       recievedDataChannel.onmessage = e=>{
           console.log("new message from remote : " +e.data);
       }

   }

   var offer = await localconn.createOffer();
   await localconn.setLocalDescription(offer);
   await remoteconn.setRemoteDescription(offer);
   var answer = await remoteconn.createAnswer();
   await remoteconn.setLocalDescription(answer);
   await localconn.setRemoteDescription(answer);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a listener for ICE candidates on the peer connection and apply those to the other peer.

```
localconn.onicecandidate = function(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    remoteconn.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
  } else {
    // All ICE candidates have been sent
  }
}

remoteconn.onicecandidate = function(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    localconn.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
  } else {
    // All ICE candidates have been sent
  }
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate